# Setting bot activity in interactions v5 aka discord-py-interactions

Tags: python, discord, discord-interactions

How can i set bot activity using interactions library?

I know that in discord.py library i can do something like

```
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix='+',activity=discord.Game(name="/help for list of commands"))
```

and based off this and other answers i tried making interactions library one:

```
bot = Client(intents=Intents.ALL, presence=interactions.ClientPresence(activities=[interactions.PresenceActivity(name="/help to get all commands", type=PresenceActivityType.WATCHING)]))
```

but it gives error

cannot import name 'ClientPresence' from 'interactions' (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\interactions_*init*_.py)